# Sum of total - year wise - with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below:

```
 col1          Date               Total                                   
 id1           2019-01-19         876         
 id1           2019-02-12         987
 id2           2019-12-12         9879
 id2           2017-07-23         27652
 id2           2018-12-09         765
 id2           2018-12-28         2987
 id1           2016-11-09         2871
 id2           2016-05-19         87687
```

I want to calculate `sum of Total in latest year - sum of Total in earliest year` with group by on `col1`

Output:

```
      col1        output               
      id1       -1008     
      id2       -77808
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't directly have "first()" and "last()" aggregation functions.  However, it does have `keep` which does the same thing with a more cumbersome syntax.

This allows you to aggregate the data by year and `col1`.  Then you can just do arithmetic on the first and last values:

```
SELECT col1,
       (MAX( sum_total ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY year DESC) -
        MAX( sum_total ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY year ASC)
       ) as output
FROM (SELECT col1, TRUNC( dt, 'YYYY') AS year,
             SUM( total ) as sum_total
      FROM   table_name
      GROUP BY col1, TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY')
     ) cy
GROUP BY col1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07b20d59133edc901ca776f12d747adc) is a db<>fiddle.